# SwiftUI: Updating ui when view is not present causes "Unable to present view. Please file a bug."

Tags: swiftui

I get the following error: `Unable to present view. Please file a bug` whenever I make an asynchronous call on a view and leave the view (e.g. navigate to another view in the navigation stack) before it can make changes to the ui. Consequently, the next view in the navigation stack is unable to update its view. How can I fix this problem?

An example of the problem occurring is when I switch from view1 to view2 before my GetIoTThingIndex() call finishes and makes an update to the ui.

```
GetIoTThingIndex.query(device) { error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

After doing more investigating, I found that this problem is due to the fact that I am implementing my logic in an MVVM pattern. When I moved my logic directly into the the view and called the functions and state variables inside the view, everything worked fine. It's interesting because when I started building my app with just a few pages with minimal logic and dependencies, this MVVM pattern worked fine without any bugs. However, when my project grew to 20+ pages with more logic and dependencies, the MVVM pattern causes this bug. Is this just a problem I see or has anyone seen anything like this before and have any recommendations for fixing it?

This is the way I had things with MVVM.

*View*

```
struct DeviceView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = DeviceViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.name)
        ...
    }
}
```

*View Model*

```
class DeviceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""

    public func updateUI() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the way I have things now (which works without this bug).

*View*

```
struct DeviceView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
        ...
    }

    @State var name = ""

    public func updateUI() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: what do you have in "func updateUI()"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is what is happening?

I've tested the idea of navigating to another view
before the parent can make a change to its view. And all works well.
This is the code I used for the test, click on the button first, then within 3 sec click on the NavigationLink.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var thingToUpdate = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (spacing: 40) {
                Text("text \(thingToUpdate)")
                Button("click me first") {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                        thingToUpdate = " is updated now"
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("the detail view")) {
                    Text("then to DetailView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit update using ObservableObject that works for me:

```
class DeviceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "no name"

    public func updateUI() {
        // simulated delay on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.name = "success"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = DeviceViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (spacing: 40) {
                Text("viewModel name is \(viewModel.name)")
                Button("click me first") {
                    viewModel.updateUI()
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("DetailView")) {
                    Text("then to DetailView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and can confirm that it works as expected. I investigated into my problem more and found it has something to do with my use of MVVM. I've updated my question above.

Comment: updated my test using DeviceViewModel. Does this work for you?